# Find the Biggest number in HashSet/HashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I would like to find the biggest number in HashSet and HashMap. Say I have the number [22,6763,32,42,33] in my HashSet and I want to find the largest number in my current HashSet..how would i do this? and Same thing for the HashMap as well. I hope you can help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to do this, you probably shouldn't be using a hash-based collection.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.max(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) to find the maximum element out of any collection.
Similarly, for a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you can use the same method on its [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) or [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29), depending upon whether you want maximum key, or maximum value.

Also, if you want as such, you can use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead, that stores the elements in sorted key order.

Comment: Wow..Thank you..it helps alot.:)

Comment: Don't forget that max() throws [NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) on empty collections.

Answer (score 12):

try

```
    int max = Collections.max(set);
    int maxKey = Collections.max(map.keySet());
    int maxValue Collections.max(map.values());
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are forced to use a `HashSet`/`HashMap`, then you have to scan the whole `HashSet`/`HashMap` in order to find the maximum. Library functions like `Collections.max()` will do like this.

If you want `O(1)` retrieval of the maximum, and you are allowed to change the type of collection being used, use a sorted set/map (e.g. `TreeSet`/`TreeMap`).

Comment: O(1) works only on map keys; for values a separate collection must be constructed first, so it's O(n) again, with a very bad constant factor.

Comment: Also note that TreeSet gets costlier for insertion and deletion. So wisely choose the right implementation

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>() {{
    add(22);
    add(6763);
    add(32);
    add(42);
    add(33);
}};
int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int value : values) {
    if (value > maxValue) {
        maxValue = value;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put("0", 22);
    put("1", 6763);
    put("2", 32);
    put("3", 42);
    put("4", 33);
}};
int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int value : values.values()) {
    if (value > maxValue) {
        maxValue = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrible way to initialize a HashMap just for that simple purpose a new class has to be created. I hate it every time I see it in code I work with.

Comment: What's so terrible?  I see no harm in it.

Comment: What I wrote above, it creates new class just for the purpose of creating map with few elements. It's very slow (there are tests on it on stackoverflow).

Comment: I'll never believe that this would be the bottleneck in any app.  Micro-optimization at its worst.

Answer (score 0):

In case of TreeMap, if you know the key/values are inserted randomly, the tree will be more or less balanced. Trees become unbalanced, if data is inserted in already sorted order, the capability to quickly find (or insert or delete) a given element is lost. In case of unbalanced tree, it will take time proportional to n, O(n) else O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/). Here is the [API docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/index.html).
The class of interest is [SummaryStatistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html). It works with `double`s and computes max, min, mean etc. on the fly (as you add values to it). The data values are not stored in memory, so this class can be used to compute statistics for very large data streams.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method which does what you are asking:

```
  public String getMapKeyWithHighestValue(HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
    String keyWithHighestVal = "";

    // getting the maximum value in the Hashmap
    int maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(map.values()));

    //iterate through the map to get the key that corresponds to the maximum value in the Hashmap
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {  // Iterate through hashmap
        if (entry.getValue() == maxValueInMap) {

            keyWithHighestVal = entry.getKey();     // this is the key which has the max value
        }

    }
    return keyWithHighestVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : If you want to find the biggest value from Map try maxEntry.get().getValue() instead of maxEntry.get().getKey()

**1. Using Stream**

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingStreamAndLambda(Map<K, V> map) {
    Optional<Entry<K, V>> maxEntry = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max((Entry<K, V> e1, Entry<K, V> e2) -> e1.getValue()
            .compareTo(e2.getValue())
        );

    return maxEntry.get().getKey();
}
```

**2. Using Collections.max() with a Lambda Expression**

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingCollectionsMaxAndLambda(Map<K, V> map) {
    Entry<K, V> maxEntry = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), (Entry<K, V> e1, Entry<K, V> e2) -> e1.getValue()
        .compareTo(e2.getValue()));
    return maxEntry.getKey();
}
```

**3. Using Stream with Method Reference**

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingStreamAndMethodReference(Map<K, V> map) {
    Optional<Entry<K, V>> maxEntry = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
    return maxEntry.get()
        .getKey();
}
```

**4. Using Collections.max()**

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingCollectionsMax(Map<K, V> map) {
    Entry<K, V> maxEntry = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), new Comparator<Entry<K, V>>() {
        public int compare(Entry<K, V> e1, Entry<K, V> e2) {
            return e1.getValue()
                .compareTo(e2.getValue());
        }
    });
    return maxEntry.getKey();
}
```

**5. Using Simple Iteration**

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingIteration(Map<K, V> map) {
    Map.Entry<K, V> maxEntry = null;
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue()
            .compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }
    return maxEntry.getKey();
}
```